# If we are cleared for an ILS approach, can we descend according to the approach chart？

Tags: instrument-procedures, ils, iaps

For example VCBI，ILS Z 04. We have ATC clearance:

> Descend and maintain 2300 feet, Cleared ILS RWY 04 approach.

Can we descend as profile 1700 and then 1500, and intercept glide path? Or maintain 2300 and intercept glide path? Or even maintain present altitude - for example 2700ft - and descend on glide path?

[image: VCBI ILS Z Rwy 04]

Answer (score 2):

```
Descend and maintain 2300 feet, Cleared ILS RWY 04 approach.
```

This clearance allows you to descend to 2300 FT MSL right away.  When you are on a published part of the procedure (i.e. on the localizer with positive course guidance) you can then descend to the altitude shown on the chart for that segment.

You can choose to remain higher to capture the glideslope or descend to the MEAs when allowed.

I am a firm believer in a stabilized approach and staying higher to capture the glideslope helps to accomplish that.  There is an issue, however, with capturing the glideslope early and following it down and it has to deal with warm weather.  In warmer than standard weather, it is possible to be on the glideslope and find yourself below the MEA for that segment of flight.

In that case, it may be best to descend to the altitudes listed on the chart until you are at final approach fix altitude and then capture the glideslope and descend.

In your specific example, I Would descend to 2300 FT MSL and capture the localizer.  I would stay at 2300 FT and descend on the glideslope.  In really warm weather, I would be cautious of my altitude crossing LAROD and GOPRU

Comment: in cold weather I keep higher altitude to capture the glide slope.When I am in glide slope cold weather is nothing to me.

Comment: I agree with you @Bianfable

Comment: Regarding, "This clearance allows you to descend to 2300 FT MSL right away..."  That clearance also *requires* you to descend to 2300', perhaps to vacate an altitude that the controller needs for somebody else.  Once established on the localizer, the published altitudes are generally (not always) "at or above" altitudes, so in those cases you can remain at 2300' to capture the GS there, or descend to whatever is on the profile, and either way you're meeting your clearance.